# VSCode individualize every instance?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is there a way to individualize single VSC instances?
I have only found Peacock, but that is too colorful.

I would prefer to be able to display a name in the title bar or above the sidebar, including the name of the workspace folder.

##### edit:

not perfect, but okay:

```json
  // will not work on workspace settings.json -> only global
  "window.titleBarStyle": "custom",
  // show only the name of the workspace folder in the title bar
  "window.title": "${folderName}",
  // remove the useless icons on the top-right
  "window.commandCenter": false,

  // make left & top green :-)
  "workbench.colorCustomizations": {
    "activityBar.background": "#1e2127",
    "activityBar.foreground": "#95C085",
    "titleBar.activeBackground": "#165900",
    "titleBar.activeForeground": "#ffffff",
  },
```

Comment: you can customize the title with a setting, and you can change it on a workspace level

Comment: I'm voting to close as duplicate of another Q&A that relates to customizing the title. If that's not a duplicate, then please limit the scope of what "individualize" means, because a number of things can be customized, making this question open-ended.

Comment: THX @rioV8 & @Gino, the `window.title` is the best i can get, it seems you can not change the font-size, the other settings are just "nice"